# javascript settimeout function in aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to hide an element after some time ( about 2 seconds ).
in javascript in can use `setTimeout` function for that. Is there a way that I could use it on Aurelia? or is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the element using the `if` custom attribute included in Aurelia. Then bind that to a property on the viewmodel.

```js
this.showItem = true;
window.setTimeout(() => this.showItem = false, 2000);
```

```html
<h1 if.bind="showItem">I will hide in 2 seconds</h1>
```

Comment: Yep, Aurelia is just JavaScript!

Comment: Thanks, buddy, I wasn't using the `window` tag